# calling member function where() on null error

Tags: php, laravel-9

My Laravel App is showing this message:

> Call to a member function where() on null

My Controller file looks:

```
    {
     $product_category=product_category::find('id')->where('id')->get();
       return view('product_category', compact('product_category'));
    }
```

Can you guys help me to solve this?

Comment: `product_category::find('id')` must have returned `null`. And obviously you can't call a function on null.

Comment: ok, but how can i fix it, how can i call function?

Comment: You need to make it return a valid value. It will return null when it doesn't find anything. Presumably the value you searched for does not exist in the database. I'd guess you intended to write an actual ID number in `find('id')`, not the word "id"?

Answer (score 1):

this syntax is not correct!

read this document for find():
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

read this document for where():
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#where-clauses

my description:

when you want to find a single product_category row you must write this (for example product_category with id 7):

```
$product_category=product_category::find(7);
```

or

```
$product_category=product_category::where('id', 1)->first();
```

when you use `first()` function at the end of your code, its return a single row and that is the first row. when using `get()` function at the end of your code, its return a set of rows that are in your Query.
when you use `find()` and its return value is null, you cant call `where()` after that!

I think you must write your controller like this:

```
public function productCategory($id)
{
   $product_category=product_category::find($id);
   return view('product_category', compact('product_category'));
}
```

I suggest you read about Laravel Eloquent much:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent

and about Laravel Query builder:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries

Comment: ok, it worked, but i get "Method App\Http\Controllers\product_categoryController::product_category does not exist." error now.

Comment: product_category is the name of your model and you must import its class name in the top of your class by `use` key word.